# How can I echo a BLOB using JSON array in php?

Tags: php, mysql, json, base64

I have seen many examples but I cannot properly echo what I am looking for. My goal is to convert the BLOB into base64 and echo the JSON array using php. I am aware that storing images in the database as BLOB is not generally the proper approach but I want to do this just for the sake of knowing how to do it (general consensus seems to be that storing references to the images which in turn are stored in the file system is the better approach). I am also well aware that there are probably multiple security issues in my php code (very new to php). I would just like to know this.

**Here is the structure of my table:**
http://s27.postimg.org/lod0ec0er/Screen_Shot_2015_05_13_at_10_49_29_PM.png

**Here are the contents of my table:**
http://s15.postimg.org/joks2fvzv/Screen_Shot_2015_05_13_at_10_51_34_PM.png

**Here is my first php code attempt (before realizing that I had to convert the BLOB to base64):**

```
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM TestImages";

    if($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {
        $resultArray = array();
        $tempArray = array();

        while($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            $tempArray = $row;
            array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
        }

        echo json_encode($resultArray);
    }

    mysqli_close($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**Here is what the above code displays (I believe image is null because JSON cannot naturally handle BLOB):**
htttp://s2.postimg.org/k2vi3r0ft/Screen_Shot_2015_05_13_at_10_52_06_PM.png

**After realizing that I have to convert BLOB to base64 here is my modified php code:**

```
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM TestImages";

    if($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {
        $resultArray = array();
        $tempArray = array();

        while($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            $row["image"] = base64_encode($row["image"]);
            $tempArray = $row;
            array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
        }

        echo json_encode($resultArray);
    }

    mysqli_close($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The above code does not even produce an empty set. It is completely blank. What am I doing wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the while loop.
You are changing the value of your row variable inside the loop which I hope invalidates the condition in the while loop and the control comes out of the loop. You have stored the base64encoding result in a different variable.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) { $row_encoding = base64_encode($row["image"]); $tempArray = $row_encoding; array_push($resultArray, $tempArray); }
```